# S3 bucket name not being displayed

Tags: amazon-s3

My problem is that the s3 bucket names are not being displayed in the web page. My code is as below:

```
var AWS = require(['aws-sdk-2.1.34.min.js']);
var app = {
initialize:function(){
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady,false);
},

onDeviceReady: function(){
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId:'MY ACCESS KEY', secretAccessKey:'MY SECRET KEY'});
    var s3Client = new AWS.S3();
    console.log("s3 :: ",s3Client);

    s3Client.listBuckets(function(err, data){ alert(345);
        if(err) alert("Error :: ", err);
        else{
            var listElement = document.createElement("ul");
            document.getElementById('bucket_list').appendChild(listElement);
            for(var index in data.Buckets){
                var bucket = data.Buckets[index];
                var listContent = document.createElement("li");
                listContent.innerHTML = "<p> Bucket Name: " + bucket.name + "</p>";
                listElement.appendChild(listContent);
               }
             }
          });
        }
     };
   app.initialize();
```

I am unable to figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see if `data.Buckets` contains any data?

Comment: Yes. When I print it in the console, I am able to see the bucket list.

Comment: Thanks John for pointing me in the right direction.It was s stupid typo error. It should be bucket.Name and not bucket.name. Problem straightened out.Thanks again